# .Net Core2 EF MySQL having issue while changing foreign key column to nullable

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on an application where I am using .Net Core 2, EF Core and MySQL as database server via Code First approach.

I have 2 tables:

1. User
2. Employee

User table is the main table which contains the user information and Employee table is the child table which has a column ID_User as shown below:

```
 public class User : BaseEntity
    {
        public int ID_User { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees{get;set;}
    }



 public class Employee : Entity
    {
        public int ID_Employee { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int ID_User { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Everything works perfectly when I use the above mapping and I have enough data in both the tables.

Now, I want to make the column **ID_User** in Employee table as **nullable**

To implement this change I made following change to my model:

```
public class Employee : Entity
    {
        public int ID_Employee { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? ID_User { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

and in mapping file:

```
builder.HasOne(x=>x.User).WithMany(y=>y.Employees).HasForeignKey(z=>z.ID_User).IsRequired(false);
```

After running the `dotnet ef migrations add empuser` command it generated the following migration code:

```
  migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Employee_User_ID_User",
            table: "Employee");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "ID_User",
            table: "Employee",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(int));

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Employee_User_ID_User",
            table: "Employee",
            column: "ID_User",
            principalTable: "User",
            principalColumn: "ID_User",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

Now when I run `dotnet ef database update` it is giving me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CONSTRAINT `FK_Employee_User_ID_User`' at line 1

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: you can try it with some other provider such as memory, so you can narrow the issue to the provider or mysql

Comment: @NevilleNazerane can you please explain more about what you want me to try with.

Comment: for mysql you would have used `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`. for now, uninstall that and install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` and `dotnet ef database update` again. If you still see an issue, it is something to do with your model code, else it is an issue specific to mysql

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Actually the project is very large and have multi tier approach and folloeing Repository/UOW pattern. If I do this change I will have to modify at many places and it will take lot of time. It would be greate if we have any other alternative for this. From the error message it is clear that the issue is from MySql because the same code was working when using with SQL server.

Comment: I've been working heavily with EF Core 2 and MySql the last couple weeks. I have been using the Pomelo provider. When I've had to drop primary keys, like what you are doing here, it typically fails. Since I'm still in greenfield dev. (product hasn't launched yet), I just clear out migrations and start over. Not an answer, for sure, but worth a try if that works in your situation.

Comment: Worth a try, also, is removing the `virtual` keyword on your `Employee.User`. I am doing a similar setup for LicenseId and SyntaxId if it helps in my project here: https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/blob/master/src/FilterLists.Data/Entities/FilterList.cs

Comment: I was using official MySQL connector, which was causing this issue. After when I switched to Pomelo, it is working fine. Thanks all for your soggestions

Answer (score 5):

Try putting the SQL statements directly into the MySQL Workbench.

1. Type "dotnet ef migrations script" in your commandprompt.
2. Copy the generated SQL script.
3. Paste it into your Workbench.
4. Check where the errors occur.

When I got similar errors using EF core 2 with MySQL this helped me understand the problem better and helped solve the problem. (for me it was a typing error). You can at least use this method to determine if it is an error in the migrations or in your SQL statements.

I know this is not a concrete solution, but I hope this will help you understand your problem and solve it :)

Comment: For those using the Package Manager Console: `Script-Migration -From firstMigration -To secondMigration`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked foreign key name in database?

I have found bug from migration builder, where creating new table:

[In my case I use EF Core 2.1 Mysql DotNet Connector bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5sr6.png)

Where migration builder creates wrongly named foreign key name...

To avoid this wrongly named foreign key name:

[fix for migration builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lihy.png)

If your foreign key is named wrongly, you can manually rename it in database and then your migration might work.

Answer (score 0):

The key word CONSTRAINT is not supported for certain version of MYSQL . EF core generates drop constraint for dropping foreign key . I have to change the following:-

```
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_XXXXX",
            table: "XXXXXX");
```

to

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER TABLE XXXXXX DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_XXXXX");
```